# calculate expectation of scalar,vector DPCM

Tags: probability

I want to implement a DPCM code for image compression.

to do the prediction i need to find the coefficients of a filter for example I need to solve $w= \frac{R}{p}$

where

$w$ is a vector (coefficients of the filter),
$R$ is a autocorrelation matrix $E[f*f']$ where $f$ is a vector of previous  encoded pixels
$p$ is a vector $E[g(n,k)*f]$ where $g(n,k)$ is the value of $(n,k)$-pixel and $f$ the same as above

I don't know how to calculate the vector $E[g(n,k)*f]$

$E[~]$ is the Expectation function.

in my book, it is estimated by the following type 
http://s8.postimage.org/w7mzsz2d1/Screenshot_1.png

but I don't understand how to calculate it. I think this formula gives scalar and not vector. Can someone decode the formula in pseudo-code please?